# Android Studio Animation class hasStarted method not working properly

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.animationcheck;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Animation anim;
    private TextView textViewHelloWorld;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewHelloWorld = findViewById(R.id.textViewHelloWorld);

        anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(50);
        anim.setStartOffset(20);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        textViewHelloWorld.startAnimation(anim);


        System.out.println(anim.hasStarted());


    }
}




System.out.println(anim.hasStarted()); displays false
```

I want to check if the animation has started, but hasStarted method returns false
Why is that so? How do I check if the animation has started?
I wonder what's the purpose of that boolean check then...

Answer (score 0):

You can use setAnimationListener it is more clean way to handle animation process. Because you call two methods synchronously.